# Which is the good way to conforms to UITableView protocols?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am following [this](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#protocol-conformance) guideline to implement `UITableView` protocols. But right now, it's showing me an error, what I am doing wrong?

> 'RequestsViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'.

---

```
class RequestsViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    ...
}

extension RequestsViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayRequests.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> RequestsTableViewCell {
        let cell:RequestsTableViewCell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! RequestsTableViewCell)
        //Doing some assignments.
        return cell
    }
}

extension RequestsViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
}
```

Comment: There is also a typo mistake in the class name and extension name

Comment: Why is suddenly using extension not as extensions the right way to conform to protocols. What happened to the //MARK: statement for readability?

Comment: @MacUserT, I was reading the guidelines [see the link] in question, for swift development, and also I came across few sources which are actually following these guidelines. Thus, it's always used to follow the tradition.

Comment: I didn't down vote the question. I just wondered why an extension should suddenly be used for readability. I haven't found those guidelines in Apple documentation yet and I'm just questioning where Ray Wenderlich has gotten these guidelines. There is a specific purpose for extensions and it is not making your code more readable. That's where the MARK statements are for. It also allows you to jump to the section in question.

Comment: @MacUserT, I am thinking on your concern but it may be Swift standards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**CHANGE THIS**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> RequestsTableViewCell
```

**TO:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Comment: Basically, you are confirming a protocol, in `UITableViewDataSource` that method returns `UITableViewCell`. By changing that the method changes. Thus the actual method is never confirmed.